# Spring boot - Threads / Feign-Client / Messaging / Streamlistener

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-feign

We struggle to find a solution for the following scenario:

**Situation**

- Receive a message via Spring Cloud Streamlistener
- Invoke a REST-Service via Feign-Client
- We have configured several Feign-RequestInterceptor to enrich
  request header data.

We want to avoid passing every request header on the method call and like the central configuration approach of the request interceptors.

**Problem:**

How to access data from a specific message, which contains informations, that need to be added to every request call via the Feign-RequestInterceptor.
We don't have a Request-Context, as we come from a message.

Can we be sure , that the message consumption and the REST call is happening on the same thread? If yes, we could use the NamedThreadLocal to store the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless you hand off to another thread in your StreamListener, the rest call will be made on the same thread (assuming you are using `RestTemplate` and not the reactive web client).